# How Can I Execute an SQL File Correctly Within MySQL in Windows 10 Command Prompt?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-10, command-prompt

I have been trying almost thirty minutes trying to figure out how to execute an sql file from a Win 10 command prompt and I still can't figure out how to do it.

I am in the mysql> directory and I can't figure out what the 'source' is before the path to the file. What is the 'source' that I need to type in before the path to the MySql file?

Here is my file path to the bookorama.sql file that I am trying to execute:
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin

The bookorama.sql is within the file path at the last 'bin' folder.

Here's what I have tried to find so far, but I keep on trying a lot of the suggestions for the answers in these posts, but I still can't get it right.

[Can't run MySQL from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812866/cant-run-mysql-from-command-prompt)

[Executing a SQL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649118/executing-a-sql-file)

[How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/17666285)

[execute .sql file using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236834/execute-sql-file-using-command-line)

https://tecadmin.net/run-sql-text-file-on-mysql-command-prompt/

Here's a copy of the command prompt tries to execute the sql file:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin>mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p
Enter password: *********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input 

mysql> use books
Database changed
mysql> -u bookorama -d books < bookoroma.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '-u bookorama -d books < bookoroma.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql' at line 1
mysql> mysql -h localhost - u bookorama -p < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -h localhost - u bookorama -p < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> cd..
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'cd..' at line 1
mysql> mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -D books -p < bookorama.sql
    ->
    -> CREATE TABLE Customers
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -D books -p < bookorama.sql

CREATE TABLE Custom' at line 1
mysql> -u bookorama -D books -P < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '-u bookorama -D books -P < bookorama.sql' at line 1mysql> -u root
    -> -p Oscar545* -D bookorama < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '-u root
-p Oscar545* -D bookorama < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysql -h localhose u-root -D bookorama < 
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin.bookorama.sql
Show warnings disabled.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -h localhose u-root -D bookorama < 
C:amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin.booko' at line 1
mysql> mysql -h localhose u-root -D bookorama < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -h localhose u-root -D bookorama < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> use books
Database changed
mysql> mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin bookorama.sql
Show warnings disabled.ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'C:amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> source C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin;
Show warnings disabled.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'C:amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin', error: 2
mysql> C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin\bookorama.sql
Show warnings disabled.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\b'.
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'C:amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin\bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysql -h localhost -u root
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -h localhost -u root' at line 1
mysql> -h localhost -root -pOscar545* books < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '-h localhost -root -pOscar545* books < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -u root -p books < bookorama.sql' at line 1
mysql>
```

Answer (score 3):

At the `mysql>` prompt you'd use:

```
use books;
source bookorama.sql;
```

At the command prompt you'd use:

```
mysql.exe -h localhost -root -pOscar545* books < bookorama.sql
```

Comment: sorry, yes, `source`. mixing languages. :)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL CLI (command line interface) like other CLIs or shell programs including databases (Postgres' psql, SQLite's sqlite3, SQL Server's sqlcmd, Oracle's sqlplus), langauges (python.exe, perl.exe, php.exe, r.exe), and others are executables (.exe) that do not launch with a GUI like most software .exes but evokes a session inside a terminal window.

Command line interpreters such as Windows' PowerShell and Cmd.exe, or Unix's (MacOS/Linux) Bash terminal are used to start such CLI sessions. Essentially, there are two ways to run MySQL commands:

1. Call `mysql.exe` with arguments without opening prolonged session.
2. Launch a mysql session and run separate calls.

Your problem is the conflation of the above two where you are attempting a command line call of `mysql.exe`  with arguments *inside* `mysql.exe` or running its top level arguments inside a session. Inside the CLI, the parser only interprets special MySQL commands like `source` and direct SQL queries not executable, `mysql`, calls or connection arguments (`-h, -u`) without its shell command caller: `\!`.

Simply use appropriate calls outside a CLI session:

```
cd C:\amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin
mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -p < bookorama.sql
```

Or inside a CLI session:

```
cd C:\amp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin
mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -p
mysql> source bookorama.sql
```

---

With that said, you can do the opposite.

- Running command queries outside:

  ```
  mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -p -e "source bookorama.sql"
  ```
- Calling terminal calls inside:

  ```
  mysql> \! mysql -h localhost -u bookorama -pXXXXX < bookorama.sql
  ```